# Postgresql 9.3 listening channels

Tags: postgresql, channel, notify, listen

PostgreSQL manual LISTEN/NOTIFY chapter does not explain clearly to me about adding a new channel.

For example, if I call

```
PERFORM pg_notify('somechannel', 'update');
```

Will it create a channel 'somechannel' automatically? (I am not asking about the client application which will listen to it; only about postgresql side).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. PostgreSQL places no major restrictions on what a channel name can be and `pg_notify()` is merely a wrapper around the `NOTIFY` command that makes use of variable information in notification easy. So, whatever channel name `NOTIFY` will accept is also acceptable input for `pg_notify()` and the channel will be created equally when specifying a non-existent channel name.